# php json_encode is not working in gulp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 5.2 , I am using like below

`var data = <?php json_encode($data['value']);  ?>`

when I am using JavaScript code below in the blade file, then its working fine, but when I am using the code as a separate file and trying to gulp that , then it is not working , my data is not loading

Comment: var data = "<?php json_encode($data['value']);  ?>";

Comment: I have tried this, but my data is not showing

Comment: there r so many solution available in answers plz try them... <?php echo json_encode($data['value']); ?>; dont forget to use ending termination semi colon

Comment: i have updated the answer use JSON.parse

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "<?=json_encode($data['value']);?>"
```

or

```
var data = "<?php echo json_encode($data['value']);?>"
```

You are not echoing out the value, your var is null

Comment: please terminate the lines :p

Comment: By mistake, I have putted it wrong here.I am echoing, but still showing the error

Comment: have you tried just encoding just $data? I am not sure exactly what you $data holds it might not have enough info to encode it @Vikash

Comment: As I told if I am using it in blade file then it's working,my data variable is fine

Comment: @Vikash can i see the blade file?

Comment: I am just trying to graps an understanding of your whole system, if one thing works and another doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Other mate already provided the correct solution specially @user1779617, now i am explaining with a basic example:

```
<?
// a simple array
$data['value'] = array(1=>'test');
$encodedData = json_encode($data['value']);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?=$encodedData?>;
console.log(data); //  Object { 1="test"}
</script>
```

If you have posted original code than you have an error in your `javascript`, you miss the ending **termination semicolon** `(;)` plus you need to `echo` the result as other mentioned in answers.

**UPDATE 1**

if you are still facing the same issue than use `JSON.parse` in `javascript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = JSON.parse( ' <?=$encodedData?>');
console.log(data); //  Object { 1="test"}
</script>
```

Comment: @Vikash: check my other solution.